# How can I track referrals with Google Analytics SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, tracking, referrals

Here I can se how to pass tracking values: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/devguide#campaigns

What I don't understand is how to pass referral info through the campaigns' links and how the app retrieves those parameters when I download the app.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell google analytics does not support referral tracking for iOS at this time.  The Apple app store is sandboxed and there is no way to pass a url with referral parameters to the app store and then onto a downloaded iOS app.  However, there are a couple sdks that do referral tracking via cookie tracking (Apsalar, MDotM, Flurry) and other sdks that do it via device identifiers (Mixpanel, hasOffers).

Comment: but how cookie will work when you can't get cookies data from safari. Or Device identifier when you don't have Device Identifier in safari...